# Output SQL table to frontend of wordpress website

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table at phpmyadmin with some test data. I was trying to output the table to wordpress page using Woody Snippet plugin. The table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `Inventory`
(`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment
,`Record` enum('','Purchase','Sale','Stock Adjustment') NOT NULL
,`Date` date NOT NULL
,`Product Name` char(255) NOT NULL
,`SKU` char(30) NOT NULL
,`SA Adjustment` enum('','Add','Substract') NOT NULL
,`PO Number` char(15) NOT NULL
,`Order ID` char(20) NOT NULL
,`Quantity` int(10) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE  INDEX `pn_sku` ON `Inventory` (`SKU`);
CREATE  INDEX `quantity` ON `Inventory` (`Quantity`);
```

Sample data as below:

```
INSERT INTO `Inventory` (`id`, `Record`, `Date`, `Product Name`, `SKU`, `SA Adjustment`, `PO Number`, `Order ID`, `Quantity`) VALUES
(14, 'Sale', '2020-08-29', 'Product A', 'PRO0001', '', '', 'SO0001', -2),
(15, 'Sale', '2020-08-29', 'Product B', 'PRO0002', '', '', 'SO0002', -5),
(16, 'Stock Adjustment', '2020-08-29', 'Product A', 'PRO0001', 'Add', '', '', 20),
(17, 'Stock Adjustment', '2020-08-29', 'Product B', 'PRO0002', 'Substract', '', '', -10),
(18, 'Purchase', '2020-08-29', 'Product A', 'PRO0001', '', 'PO0001', '', 50),
(19, 'Purchase', '2020-08-29', 'Product B', 'PRO0002', '', 'PO0002', '', 100);
```

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O4wI.png)

I am trying to output the table in a summary version, grouping the same Product Name and SKU, and SUM the Quantity.

I run the below SQL on phpmyadmin and it show the data and table as I want.

```
SELECT `Product Name`, `SKU`, SUM(`Quantity`) FROM `Inventory`
GROUP BY `Product Name`, `SKU`
```

My output code as below. I am new in this. Hope to get some guide. Thanks!

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost"; 
$username="invdb"; 
$password="invpw"; 
$database="tbbcom_inv"; 
  
$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database); 
if(!$con) 
{ 
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

$result=mysqli_query("SELECT Product Name, SKU, SUM(Quantity) FROM Inventory GROUP BY Product Name, SKU");
?>

<table align="center" border="1px" style="width:100%; line-height:40px;">
    <tr>
        <th> Product Name </th>
        <th> SKU </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
    </tr>
    
    <?php
        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
    ?>
    
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['Product Name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['SKU']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows[‘SUM(Quality)’]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: *How* does it not work? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: Hi John, I have tested the connection by putting the wrong database password and it show the connection failed note. BTW, where should I place the mysqli_error()? Sorry for the stupid question. I do not have proper education on mysql. Just did some reading here and there.

Comment: Hi John, I added <?php mysqli_error(); ?> to the last part. But it did not show anything. Am I doing it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Whould be better to post sample data as sql insert statement.

Comment: Hi Slava, I have inserted into the post. Thanks!

Comment: `Product Name` is not a good column name. You need to use backticks everytime you use that. You have failed to do that here which is causing errors. (`SA Adjustment` is a similiar scenario although not being used here) Your `$rows[‘SUM(Quality)’]` is using MS smart quotes, not standard quotes, that should also be throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not good idea to create DB table with column name with spaces like `Product Name`. It cause to all you problems.
But if you have strong will to do it please quote it by backtikcs:

```
 <?php
    $hostname="localhost"; 
    $username="invdb"; 
    $password="invpw"; 
    $database="tbbcom_inv"; 
  
    $con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database); 
    if(!$con) 
    { 
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }

    $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `Product Name`, `SKU`, SUM(`Quantity`) FROM `Inventory` GROUP BY `Product Name`, `SKU`");
    ?>
    
    <table align="center" border="1px" style="width:100%; line-height:40px;">
        <tr>
            <th> Product Name </th>
            <th> SKU </th>
            <th> Quantity </th>
        </tr>
        
        <?php
            while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
        ?>
        
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['Product Name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['SKU']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['SUM(`Quantity`)']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </table>
```

You can test working example here [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=b97b4f6ff4f160ad6c9c9d618c09f8fb&sqlses=12dc5bff879ddb458451d133251e0721)

Comment: Hi Slava, thanks for your advice! I have changed my DB accordingly. Then, I tested it on PHPize.online you provided. I run it on php7 version and still get an error "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result". I think I can only paste the code in the following answer section.

Comment: Hi Slava, after I did a clean pasting of SQL code and PHP code, it works now on PHPize.online. But, I still can't get it to appear on my website. Wonder there might be some setting that is wrong.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't know. One more what I can to advice is alias for `SUM(quantity)` change query to `SELECT productName, sku, SUM(quantity) as total FROM inventory_record GROUP BY productName, sku` and `<td><?php echo $rows['total']; ?></td>` https://phpize.online/?phpses=b90859d6e9a6317a55ebd17862f7cb34&sqlses=11622a1ab41c982f197118f87a37c6b4&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Thanks Slava! Still failed. It is ok. There must be a way to solve it. I will continue to look for the solution. Thanks for being a good teacher to me. Thanks again!